# Infer Prisma response type from usage

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a code like this:

```js
class SelectorFindUniqueArgsBuilder {
  async build(selector: domain.Selector) {
    return {
      where: {
        kind: selector.kind
      },
      select: {
        clarification: true,
      }
    }
  }
}

const args = await new SelectorFindUniqueArgsBuilder().build(
  selectors.role,
)

/*
type Response = {
    clarification: prisma.Clarification;
}
*/
type Response = Prisma.SelectorGetPayload<typeof args>
```

`typeof args` should match `Prisma.SelectorFindUniqueArgs`, but it doesn't now.So I modified this code to this:

```js
async build(selector: domain.Selector): Promise<prisma.Prisma.SelectorFindUniqueArgs> {
```

But now `Response` is incorrect

```js
type Response = {
    id: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    kind: "Role";
    clarificationId: string;
}
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Prisma.validator<Prisma.TableSelect>()({ ...query... })`

```
export const ourCarrierQuery = Prisma.validator<Prisma.OurCarrierSelect>()({
    ourCarrierID: true,
    // ... more ...

    // Even nested queries work and are type-safe!
    Carrier: {
        select: {
            carrierID: true,
            city: true,
        },
    },
});

export type OurCarrierResultFromDB = Prisma.OurCarrierGetPayload<{
    select: typeof ourCarrierQuery,
}>;
```